# Allow editing in NSTextView on Only User-Input and Not Software Printed Strings (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

I have an NSTextView that's been serving as console output for an NSTask/NSPipe. I'd like to add stdin, but I need a good strategy for preventing the user from editing the entire text field. Basically just like terminal. The whole field should be selectable, but only user-added text should be editable.

Does anyone know a reliable/good strategy for preventing the user from editing any strings that they did not write, even if it's not using an NSTextView?

Comment: Isn't it the matter of chechking the current carriage return position?

Comment: Perhaps, but that would depend on where the user clicked originally as well, assuming you make the text view editable. In that case you'd also have to track the current printed strings range, and force the cursor to the end of that.

Comment: Some ideas: Make the text view selectable, implement `keyDown:` somewhere  and add typed characters to the end of the text? Or add a custom attribute to the immutable text and implement the delegate method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRanges:replacementStrings:`?

Comment: I'll explore that